# How to setup the reverse of ssh -D?

Tags: ssh, proxy

I have two machines: my laptop and a remote server. The server sits behind a firewall that only allows incoming ssh connections. I can use ssh on my laptop to login to the server without any issues.
Since I don't want to (can't) change the firewall, I'd still like to be able to run `apt-get upgrade` and similar commands on the server, and thought that I could easily do the "reverse" of `ssh -D 1234 user@remote` - ie change the `-D` to something else so that I get a "reverse socks proxy" available on the remote end. (This I could later use, after setting up the right environment variables.)

Both machines run Ubuntu 15.04 and I'm using OpenSSH.

What command (or commands) should I issue in order to setup a tunnel with SSH, which has a proxy on my end (the laptop with internet access) and the remote server (which only accepts incoming tcp on port 22)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized I could solve this with two commands. On the laptop, establish a port with a tunnel back to the laptop:

```
ssh -R 10002:localhost:22 user_server@server
```

and on the server open a proxy, using that tunnel:

```
ssh -D 8080 -p 10002 user_laptop@localhost
```

Answer (score 5):

[OpenSSH 7.6](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6) introduced reverse dynamic proxy as a native option. It is implemented entirely in the client, so the server does not need to be updated.

```
ssh -R 1080 server
```

Comment: More details https://medium.com/faun/simple-socks-proxy-for-closed-network-via-ssh-reverse-tunnel-c2d91779cc6e